# Symfony 6 FormType - How to get parameter from Object inside Object

Tags: php, html, forms, crud, symfony6

I use Symfony 6 and I'm trying to get parameter - list of values (ChoiceType) from Object -> Prodline inside another Object -> Logging (relation in the database between objects) when I try create new element.

I generated Entities by command "make:entity" and using Doctrine, I generated a CRUD of them (Prodline and Logging - relation OneToMany - 1 logging can have 1 prodline, but 1 prodline can have many loggings).

Prodline has some data in the database and now I want to select a parameter/column and display it as a ChoiseType/List inside a view to create a new login.

I know I can use magic method - __toString() inside Prodline but i need several parameters in different views and I don't know how can I get/choose parameters what I want.

Prodline.php

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ProdlineRepository::class)]
class Prodline
{
    ...

    #[ORM\Column(length: 80, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $prodlinename = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $infoText = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'prodline', targetEntity: Logging::class)]
    private Collection $loggings;  

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->loggings = new ArrayCollection();

    }

   /**
     * @return Collection<int, Logging>
     */
    public function getLoggings(): Collection
    {
        return $this->loggings;
    }

    ...
}
```

Logging.php

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: LoggingRepository::class)]
class Logging
{
    ...

    #[ORM\Column(length: 8)]
    private ?string $user = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Prodline::class, inversedBy: 'loggings')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'prodline_id', referencedColumnName: 'id', nullable: false)]
    private ?Prodline $prodline = null;

    ...
    
    public function getProdline(): ?Prodline
    {
        return $this->prodline;
    }

    public function setProdline(?Prodline $prodline): self
    {
        $this->prodline = $prodline;

        return $this;
    }
    ...
```

And now what generated CRUD:
LoggingController.php

```
#[Route('/logging')]
class LoggingController extends AbstractController
{
    ...

    #[Route('/new', name: 'app_logging_new', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
    public function new(Request $request, LoggingRepository $loggingRepository): Response
    {
        $logging = new Logging();
        
        $form = $this->createForm(LoggingType::class, $logging);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $loggingRepository->save($logging, true);

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_logging_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
        }

        return $this->renderForm('logging/new.html.twig', [
            'logging' => $logging,
            'form' => $form,
        ]);
    }
     ...
}
```

FormType for create new logging:
LoggingType.php

```
class LoggingType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('user')
            ->add('prodline')
            ...
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Logging::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Templates html.twig:

new.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

    {{ include('logging/_form.html.twig') }}

{% endblock %}
```

_form.html.twig

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <button class="btn">{{ button_label|default('Save') }}</button>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

I tried many things like:

1.Added ProdlineRepository to LoggingController and findAll() records and get Prodlinename parameter as array.

```
private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    ...

    #[Route('/new', name: 'app_logging_new', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
    public function new(Request $request, LoggingRepository $loggingRepository): Response
    {
        $logging = new Logging();

        $prodlineRepository = $this->em->getRepository(Prodline::class);
        $prodline = $prodlineRepository->findAll();

        $logging->setProdlineName($logging->getProdlineNameArray($prodline));
        
        $form = $this->createForm(LoggingType::class, $logging);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $loggingRepository->save($logging, true);

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_logging_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
        }

        return $this->renderForm('logging/new.html.twig', [
            'logging' => $logging,
            'form' => $form,
        ]);
    }
```

Then added an extra parameter (array prodlineName) in Logging.php to get list of prodlineNames from Prodline.php (got 3 elements) and add this parameter to LoggingType but I get Errors like "Can't displey array as a string" ect.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('user')
            ->add('prodlineName')
            ...
    }
```

2. Tried add options in LoggingType like:

```
     $builder
 
            ->add('user')
            ->add('prodlineName', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Prodline::class,
                'multiple' => true,
                }
            ])
            // ->add('prodline', EntityType::class, [
            //     'class' => Prodline::class,
            // ])
            // ->add('prodline', ChoiceType::class, [
            //     'choice_value' => function (?Logging $entity) {
            //         return $entity ? $entity->getProdline()->getProdlinename() : '';
            //     }
            //     // 'choice_value' => 'prodlineName'
            // ])
            // ->add('prodlineName', ChoiceType::class)
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).